# how to get github html div element gist id

Tags: javascript, html, github, clipboard.js

I use GitHub gist to load my sample code to my personal blog. I design a webpage and gist is loaded. each gist create a div element:

```
<div id="gist*********" class="gist"></div>
```

also see this image:
[github gist div id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N72uW.png)

I using clipboard.js to copy my gist to the clipboard with the target. the target is an id that begins with gist word. now I want to reach this id but I cannot find any way. **any idea?**

*notice: I am blogger and I need to create many gists in a blog post so I must use a target with clipboard.js*

**sample codes:**

button code:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary copy-to-clipboard font-weight-bold" data-clipboard-target="#gist100405804">copy<i class="fas fa-copy ml-2"></i></button>
```

init clipboard js:

```
new ClipboardJS('.copy-to-clipboard');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[id^="gist"]` this will select all elements starting with `gist` value

```js
console.log($('[id^="gist"]').text())
```

```css
[id^="gist"]{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gist01654">a</div>
<span id="gist_4">b</span>
<div id="654gist">c</div>
<div id="gis01654">d</div>
```

Comment: nice dude, it works but consider that if I have two gists then this code selects both ids and it causes problems for make target in clipboard.js!

Comment: You may need to run loop through it and get the targeted element.